# R: how to avoid explicit names when using a variable

Tags: r, finance, quantmod

I have the following code in R:

```
library(quantmod)

mySymbol = "^STOXX50E"
getSymbols(mySymbol, from="2004-01-01", to=Sys.Date())

chartSeries(Cl(STOXX50E))
```

which simply download the time series for the inder Eurostoxx and then plots the closing price. 
It works as expected. 
Anyway, I was wondering how I can avoid to write explicitely "STOXX50E" everytime I want to reference to this variable. 
For example, I would like to be able to reference the variable that contains the data with a generic name like "INDEX" so that I don't need to change all the calls when I want to launch the code with another inder.

For example, if i want to download and plot the closing price for the S&P500 I have to do:

```
library(quantmod)

mySymbol = "^GSPC"
getSymbols(mySymbol, from="2004-01-01", to=Sys.Date())

chartSeries(Cl(GSPC))
```

so I have to change the variable name not only on the second line but also on the last. 
I would rather something more generic like:

```
library(quantmod)

mySymbol = "^GSPC"
getSymbols(mySymbol, from="2004-01-01", to=Sys.Date())

chartSeries(Cl(mySymbol))
```

So that once I have set the name for mySymbol I don't have to change all the rest of the code. But this doesn't work. 
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
library(quantmod)

mySymbol = "^STOXX50E"
getSymbols(mySymbol, from="2004-01-01", to=Sys.Date())

chartSeries(Cl(get(substring(mySymbol,2,nchar(mysymbol)))))
```

If you want to change the title of the plot do:

```
chartSeries(Cl(get(substring(mySymbol,2,nchar(mysymbol)))), name=mySymbol)
```

Essentially when you use `getSymbols` a variable named `STOXX50E` is stored on your global environment which contains the data. Using `get` you can access a variable name by providing a string i.e. "^STOXX50E". I then use `substring` to avoid the first character of the variable mySymbol which is `^`.

And it works. You essentially change `mySymbol` and the code runs without having to alter anything else!

[image]

**EDIT:**

This is probably a better way in terms that the code is more readable and you avoid the annoying `^` in the title:

```
library(quantmod)

mySymbol = "STOXX50E"
getSymbols(paste('^',mySymbol,sep=''), from="2004-01-01", to=Sys.Date())

chartSeries(Cl(get(mySymbol)),name=mySymbol)
```

[image]

Comment: That is great! Thank you. Do you also know how to remove the title name in the chart. Now, after your fix, the name is very long...

Comment: You are welcome! I updated my answer. In order to change the name you pass in the `name` argument.

Comment: I also provided an edit with a clearer solution which I think looks prettier. It uses `paste` for the `getSymbols` function  (to add `^`) and then only uses `get` in a simple way for `chartSeries`.

Comment: Oh and if you want to remove the name completely just use `''` as the name.

Comment: Great. Problem solved and thanks to you I learnt something new.

Comment: Really glad I could be of help :) !!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the currently accepted solution is to use `auto.assign=FALSE` in your call to `getSymbols`.

```
library(quantmod)
mySymbol <- "^STOXX50E"
x <- getSymbols(mySymbol, from="2004-01-01", to=Sys.Date(), auto.assign=FALSE)
chartSeries(Cl(x), name=mySymbol)
# If you want to remove the "^" from the name:
chartSeries(Cl(x), name=sub("^","",mySymbol,fixed=TRUE))
```

I prefer this solution because I find the coder clearer and easier to understand.